# How to debug an app running in assigned access mode on a windows 10 machine?

Tags: windows-store-apps, remote-debugging, windows-10

I am trying to analyse a crash on a windows 10 universal app running on a windows 10 PC using assigned app. Now that only one app can run at a time , in assigned access mode, I cannot run VS remote debugger. Is there an alternative method to debug a windows store app from a remote machine?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the Remote debugger to run as  a service in the "Remote Debugger Configuration Wizard". This will allow the remote debugger and your assigned access app to run at the same time.
I didn't try this, but I think it should work.

[image]

Comment: I am trying this today, I will let you know.

Comment: I am getting an error "DEP0100 : Deployment failed due to a Developer Licensing issue. " when running remote  debugger as a  service. it is working fine when In normal standalone mode.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official way to do this according to Microsoft. But the suggested workaround is to run the debugger process from a remote PC using [PSTools](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psexec.aspx)

To launch the remote debugger run the following command

```
psexec \\<computer name> /i /u <computer name>\<The logon user name of Assigned Access> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64\msvsmon.exe"
```